# Stop "My Calendar" from appearing beside Shared Calendar on startup

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I have a company Shared Calendar which I use as my main one, But the "My Calendar" Calendar keeps opening beside the Shared one and I need to untick it all of the time... How can I stop the "My calendar" from showing on start up of outlook and just have the Shared one appear?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out. The issue was that with it being a shared mailbox it was not directly linked to my Outlook profile. However when I added the group shared mailbox through Account Setting > Advanced, I had an option underneath "My Calendar" for the group calendar once I ticked this, it was used as my default calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible as the Shared Calendars aren't your primary Calendar (i.e. Linked to your e-mail account).

There is a work-around that might help though:

Move your calendar down the list of available calendars - so your calendar would still be displayed, however you would see the shared calendar first.
[image: Calendars - Shared First]

To move you calendar down the list, just right-click on it and click the "Move Down" option.

In summary, your calendar would still be displayed when you open the Calendars view, however it will not be the first that you see.

If I find anything else online that will be useful, or solves the issue for you, I will come back to this post and update it.

HTH